# Geometric proof of uniqueness and existence of ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In Arnold's book on ordinary differential equations, he proves the existence and uniqueness of one dimensional ordinary differential equations of the form

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = v(x) $$

by first showing that at poins with $v(x_0) \neq 0$, we have unique solutions described by the equation

$$ t - t_0 = \int_{x_0}^x \frac{dy}{v(y)} $$

and for $v(x_0) = 0$, assuming $v$ is Lipschitz here, the function approaches $x_0$ too slowly, and as such integral curves approaching $x_0$ take infinite time to reach $x_0$ (the integral formula above diverges if we let $x_0$ converge to a point where the vector field vanishes). Arnold later indicates in an exercise that this is an idea behind a general method for proving the uniqueness of differential equations. However, I can't seem to prove the method in general myself, and it seems every reference I find relies on Picard's method for iteratively constructing a differential equation. Would anyone be able to tell me if I'm going in the wrong direction, or point me to a source with this result if I do?

Comment: It is possible that he hints at the Grönwall theorem that can be used to estimate how fast different solutions can move away from each other. You get to solve $\|\dot r\|\le L·\|r\|$ where $r=y_2-y_1$ to get $\|r(t)\|\le  e^{Lt}\|r(0)\|$.